# how to setup constraint for 2 labels and one image view in Tableview Cell using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints

I am new to swift development. I am stuck at one point. I want to add 2 labels and one image view side by side like shown below in the image. I have tried many combination but unable to achieve the desired result. I even tried placing both labels in one container view and image view in another container view and set the constraints to it but no success. Below is the output which I want to achieve.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `UIStackview`. It is much more easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, a picture can represent it in a better way. Please follow below steps to apply the constraints to your view:

***1) Apply trailing, width and height to your image view. Still absence of y-position will throw error. Will handle in next image.***

[image]

***2) Align the image view, vertically centre to superview.***

[image]

***3) Do the same as step 1 and step 2 for you time label as well. Just give the leading constraint rather than trailing.***

[image]

[image]

***4) Give the leading and trailing constraints to name label and align it vertically centre to superview. Because you have given the widths to time label and image view to it will cover rest of the available width with 3 px padding from front and back.***

[image]

[image]

**5) Now, you will see a warning for this view, It is because you have fixed the time label's width and what happen if text will be larger for this label?. You can handle this situation by 2 methods**

***First, change the `autoshrink` property from `Fixed Font Size` to `Minimum Font Scale` with factor 0.5. But it will just handle the case and will not remove warning. ***

[image]

***Second, update width constraint of time label with `>=`. But it will again create error because updating constraint to `>=` will conflict with name label's automatic width detection. To solve this follow next image***

[image]

6) Decrease `Horizontal Content Hugging Property` of name label.

[image]

Comment: your solution worked but when I change the orientation Image view goes outside the Tableview in iPhone X.

Comment: Awesome Worked perfect. My tableview was having space in left and right that's why image view was going outside in iPhone X. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Apply Constraints like below:**

**Label 1:**

[image]

**Label 2:**

[image]

**Imageview :**

[image]

hope,it's help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal stack view. In that you can place your labels and image horizontally.